# UnauthorizedAccessException on writing XML to a file

Tags: c#, xml, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I am trying to work with some Data Binding in a Windows 8 Store App. In my project I have a Folder which I called `Data`. In this there's one file, `Names.xml`

The xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<names>
  <name>TestName1</name>
</names>
```

I can read from this file, using this method:

```
public async void readFromXML()
{
    var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    _Folder = await _Folder.GetFolderAsync("Data");

    var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync("Names.xml");

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    var _Content = await Windows.Storage.FileIO.ReadTextAsync(_File);

    document.LoadXml(_Content);

    XmlNodeList names = document.SelectNodes("/names/name");

    foreach(var node in names)
    {
        Insert(0, new Person(node.InnerText));
    }
}
```

This all works and the one name does get read.

Now I want to save new data to this XML file in a similar manner (or any way that works really...)

I have no idea how I could do this, I tried this but it is not working:

```
public async void saveToXML()
{
    var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
    _Folder = await _Folder.GetFolderAsync("Data");

    var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync("Names.xml");

    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    XmlElement root = document.CreateElement("names");
    document.AppendChild(root);

    XmlElement naam = document.CreateElement("name");
    naam.InnerText = "TestNaam2";
    root.AppendChild(naam);

    await Windows.Storage.FileIO.WriteTextAsync(_File, document.getXml());
}
```

When I try running this I get a UnauthorizedAccessException... (I am aware that the previous method will overwrite, but that wouldn't be a problem, I just want it to write in the first place.)

What am I doing wrong and how should I go about doing this? Windows 8 Apps are quiet difficult for reading and writing XML...

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds to me like you are opening the vile twice somewhere. Either you are saving an instance of the `_File` object (as is implied by the underscore '_') or you are calling `saveToXml` twice, as you have it as `async void`, so whatever call it has no way to wait upon its completion. It's also possible that you can't write to `InstalledLocation`. Look into using an [AppDataContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700361.aspx) for storing local data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the access to the folder

```
var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
```

is restricted. Try to run your app as administrator.

Or even better try to use the local storage folder for your app:

```
var _Folder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

### Update:

You cannot see the `LocalFolder` in your Visual Studio project. But you can ship the default XML file with your app and move it to LocalFolder if it doesn't exist there. Let's create a helper function:

```
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> GetLocalFile(string folderName, string fileName)
{
    var appLocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
    var appInstallLocation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;

    var dataFolder = await appLocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync(folderName) as Windows.Storage.StorageFolder;

    if (dataFolder == null)
    {
        // the folder with given name does not exist in ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder
        // so we have to create it
        dataFolder = await appLocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync(folderName);
    }

    var localFile = await dataFolder.TryGetItemAsync(fileName) as Windows.Storage.StorageFile;

    if (localFile == null)
    {
        // local file does not exist - so we copy it from application install folder to
        // our local data folder
        var installDataFolder = await appInstallLocation.GetFolderAsync(folderName);
        var sourceFile = await installDataFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
        localFile = await sourceFile.CopyAsync(dataFolder);
    }

    return localFile; 
}
```

And just replace this part of your `readFromXML()` function:

```
var _Folder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
_Folder = await _Folder.GetFolderAsync("Data");

var _File = await _Folder.GetFileAsync("Names.xml");
```

With the call to our new helper function:

```
var _File = await GetLocalFile("Data", "Names.xml");
```

Comment: Can I see this local storage folder somewhere in the solution explorer?

Comment: Thanks, looks like this could do the trick. But is there any way I can check the contents of that folder so I can check if the file gets generated correctly? I would also need a way to delete the file while testing (not necessarily from code but just in Windows Explorer)... Could you tell me where that folder is located? Thanks!

Comment: Nevermind, found it in this path: "C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Packages\<appname/ identifier>\LocalState\" Thanks a lot for your help Marcus, I'll mark yours as the answer! Thanks!!