# Getting UnauthorizedAccessException when acessing a Xml file via the .load method C#

Tags: c#, xml, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

Currently I have been loading xml files based on user input from a textbox in a UWP app I am making. The app itself is designed to edit existing files while also display it (kind of like a text editor but only changing attributes and not the form of the file)

This all works fine for any file within my H drive (which I think is entirely local) but not from my C drive or any other network drive. Below is the section where I start loading the user's file at the very start of the application.

```
XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(fileAddress.Text);
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
try{
                    
doc.Load(fileAddress.Text);
}
catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
Debug.WriteLine("couldn't access file here");
}
```

Below is the error code I get without the catch with my C drive which is what I want to know how I can avoid (i.e. actually access the file)

```
Access to the path 'C:\Users\x\Documents\XML_Files\IEC_EI_AR_XMLDesign.xml' is denied.
```

Below is a path that does work (in my D drive) for the same file:

```
H:\XML_Files\IEC_EI_AR_XMLDesign.xml
```

I have looked into other posts and they don't seem to help or don't address this specific issue (certain drives working while certain drives not working). I tried these solutions here which seem pretty reasonable but they didn't work or were out of date

[I need to save the XML file using linq with xml code in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40239476/i-need-to-save-the-xml-file-using-linq-with-xml-code-in-c-sharp)

I know that I might be needing to change the permissions of these folders or give Visual Studio/my program heightened permissions to let the user access their own drive though I am not quite sure where/how I could do this. Additionally, any solution I would still want to maintain read/write privileges.

Any advice or suggestions/referals are appreciated!

Comment: Is your code being run by user *x*? If not, you won't have access to their folders.

Comment: x is my user account but it doesn't work regardless of the user. I have tried running visual studio as administrator too so wouldn't this give permission? Though I do think you are onto something as the network drives(without users) also works but my question still stands as to how I would get/enable access to these folders?

Comment: Running as admin doesn't automatically give you access to all user folders, despite popular belief. Can you use the same path in the location bar of Explorer to view that folder? Can you use that same path from a command prompt to change to that folder?

Comment: In both these cases with the C drive and the D drive paths the explorer with open the file using the path stored in ```fileAddress.Text``` and in both cases trying to cd to them causes an invalid path. This is why I don't get why the D drive path one works while the C Drive path doesn't even though the path is valid. Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: Are you expecting to be able to _modify_ the file, or do you just need to be able read it? Would probably also be helpful to mention what type of application this is being executed from.

Comment: Why do you use both `XmlTextReader` and `XmlDocument` for the same file?

Comment: @TiesonT. Yes to both modifying the file but also reading it.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov  I use XmlTextReader to display the xml in a section of the app further down and use xml document to make modifications. Is that a problem as I don't think its relevant for this question?

Comment: Unless you can provide a [mcve] that reliably reproduces this problem, it will not be possible to give a good answer to the question rather than a random guess, and indeed the problem would not be a reasonable question for Stack Overflow anyway, because it would not be a _programming problem_ per se, but rather a general computer user question. ...

Comment: ... Suffice to say, access to the file is being blocked for some reason, exactly as the exception is telling you. If you are using Windows 10, make sure that you either have turned off the "Controlled Folder access" feature, or have given your program permission to access that folder (to name one common reason a program might have trouble accessing a user's documents, even when running that program as that user)

Comment: @PeterDuniho The controlled folder access feature seems to be disabled/missing on my computer and I have tried giving my C drive the same access users as my H drive but no luck. The issue definitely lies with the program itself not being able to access the drive or my own organization's security. I would need some more feedback/advice before I would want to go them about this. Additionally I am sorry that this doesn't have your minimal reproducible example that you want but even if it did, the conversions and ideas are equal or even better for me than an exact solution as I get to learn a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround from the bottom comment of this answer [UnauthorizedAccessException on writing XML to a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992962/unauthorizedaccessexception-on-writing-xml-to-a-file#comment33417557_22007063) by saving/storing my files in "C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Packages<appname/ identifier>\LocalState"

This allows me to save/edit files in my C Drive (with user permission I guess) though I can now look into expanding these permissions to folders above this.